# How to share collision layer to every objects?

Tags: xna, 2d, collision-detection, collision

Currently, each level has 3 layers :

- background
- collisions(walls, invisible walls, ground, etc)
- foreground

My character sprite has 1 pixel to detect the collision.
In this character class, there is a Color[] contains every pixels of the collision layer.

I calculate the position of the Character's pixel detection, and obtain an int that i can use with the `Color[]` ("CharactersPixel")

```
if ( Color[CharactersPixel].A != 0 )
    Then collision.
```

It works perfectly.

But the collision layer has to be used by every others objects like particles, monsters etc.

The collision layer has about 3.800.000 pixels. so the `Color[]` has the same.

If I add this `Color[]` to every objects, this will use too much RAM, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd only add a *reference* to your collision layer to the objects. You are not copying the entire thing to each object. Adding a reference will not add much memory to your objects.

However, I would suggest making the collision available in some more general fashion by exposing some level data in a place accessible to any object. Perhaps you could add the data to your `Game` class as a property `CurrentLevel` with `CollisionData` as an accessible property.

Normally you keep the collision data separate from the actual rendering colours, and perform a more simplistic collision with boxes and the like instead that approximately match the shape of the collision data. This would in the end make it easier to calculate things like the angle which you impact the environment and calculation of appropriate physics. Pixel to pixel collisions are rare, and might also be problematic from a performance perspective.

Comment: Dervall is right. Pixel by pixel isn't the way to go. It's far more preferrable to create drawable objects with bounding box/sphere/polygon based detection. That way you're sharing your collisions between objects, not layers. That, and it's far more efficient.

Comment: Ok, thx for your answers. i'll wait few hours and see if someone cill give me some more tips, and i'll validate your answer. thx !

Comment: Ok, so, i'll keep my collision detection per-pixel for my character and monsters (because of the level design with slopes etc), and use the shape collision detection for the others objects.
Thx for the tips !
(i didn't try adding references, so i'll maybe need your help, again)

Comment: @Dervall Hum, for my example, i have to put "public static Level CurrentLevel" in my mainClass to allow my CharacterClass to get the Color[], right ? In my character class, the code will be like this : Game.CurrentLevel.CollisionData[CharactersPixel]; am I right ?